# JDBC ConnectException: null (ARRAY) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-connect

I have been trying to produce data using Javaclient and store data in postgres using sink-connector. i can post data into topic in protobuf format, but sink-connector seems not working. Just make sure that data being posted and available in topic, i built consumer in Java-client, and i can see data.

So data is there in topic, but something wrong with my sink-connector config. please find config details below, any help much appreciated!

> **connect-standalone.properties:**
>
> bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
>
> key.converter=com.blueapron.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
>
> value.converter=com.blueapron.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
>
> key.converter.schemas.enable=false
>
> value.converter.schemas.enable=true
>
> offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
>
> offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

---

> **connect-postgres-protobuf.properties:**
>
> name=sink-postgres
> connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
>
> tasks.max=2 topics=docker-proto-topic
>
> connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kafka-test
>
> connection.user=postgres connection.password=*** insert.mode=insert
>
> value.converter=com.blueapron.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
>
> value.converter.protoClassName=com.test.extraction.model.protobuf.AlbumOuterClass$Album
>
> key.converter=com.blueapron.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
>
> auto.create=true auto.evolve=false
>
> offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/post-sink.offsets

**Album Data:**

```
artist: "Tears For Fears"
song_title: "Songs from the Big Chair"
```

**Error Log:**

```
[task-thread-sink-postgres-1] INFO io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect - Checking PostgreSql dialect for existence of table "docker-proto-topic-2"

[task-thread-sink-postgres-1] INFO io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect - Using PostgreSql dialect table "docker-proto-topic-2" absent

[task-thread-sink-postgres-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask - WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-postgres-1} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted.

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: null (ARRAY) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getSqlType(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1727)
```

Comment: Please share any logs that are relevant to your connector task

Comment: @cricket_007: I have updated the post with logs details.

Comment: Have you tried not putting arrays into your proto message? `(ARRAY) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type `

Comment: I'm not sure that why its complains about Array, i have schema with only String; please shed some lights here

Comment: Please show your Protobuf schema and the generated Java class

Comment: @cricket_007: Its my bad! i have schema with repeated keyword(for array). Sorry couldn't respond early.